Neewer z2 and Neewer trigger not talking
Having a bit of trouble getting my Neewer QPRO-N trigger to talk to my Newwer Z2n. I have a Nikon z8. Channel is set to 01 on both. Both have fresh batteries. Trigger mounted in hot shoe and camera turned on. Green light on trigger. Test. Nothing. The manuals are tiny type, gray print on white paper and hard to read. There is a screen that is not in the manual on the flash that reads “WL Off” “RX” “TX”. What the heck does THAT mean? I’m pretty savvy… had my own studio with Profoto lighting, which I liquidated when I downsized, but this one has me confounded. I’m sure there’s a simple explanation, but it’s eluding me. Any help, deeply appreciated.

The WL terminology is weird, as that's Sony's name for their OEM wireless flash system, but Neewer (Meike?) may be using it to simply mean wireless. Looking in the user manual on page 15, this screen appears when you press the horizontal lightning bolt button to select how you want the flash be set for wireless communication.
If the speedlight is used on-camera and you want to trigger it by the foot, you set WL Off; if you want to use it as your on-camera radio transmitter, you select Tx (transmit in radio engineering-speak); if you want to use the flash off-camera as a radio receive, you select Rx (receive).
Another possibility for the transmitter and flash to not be talking to each other is more-hidden: mismatching ID settings (page 17). ID codes are used to prevent other users on the same channel in the vicinity from firing your lights. It's a sort of digital filter on top of the analog channel. So, check that the ID setting is identical on both the flash and the transmitter. And maybe consider using the SCAN function (page 17) to find the least-crowded channel to use, instead of the default Channel 1.

Thanks so much… but there is an N on the order… and N on the box… and an N on the unit. Unless all are mislabeled, I don’t believe that’s the issue. Good guess, though. Thanks again.

@JaimeKlein, okay dipped into the manual (I was a pro tech writer for 25+ years, so it's easier for me to suss the damn things out) and have rewritten the answer with an explanation of that screen and two more possibilities/fixes for the non-communication: ID codes and changing channels. :D
